# If I'm using nested classes or structs for several levels in Swift, are there going to be performance problems?

Tags: swift, performance, inner-classes

Say I want to categorised something by using nested classes or structs like this.

```
extension String 
{
   struct Localized
   {
      struct Item
      {
         struct Edit
         {
            struct Alert
            {
               struct Title
               {
                  static var someTitle: String { return NSLocalizedString("...", comment: "...") }
               }

               struct Message
               {
                  static var someMessage: String { return NSLocalizedString("...", comment: "...") }
               }
            }
         }

         static var someString: String { return NSLocalizedString("...", comment: "...") }
      }
   }
}
```

What if I have more several levels deep, are there going to be much performance problems or it just uses too much unnecessary memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of Swift's strong typing, there will be no performance hit doing something like this with structs. The compiler will be able to resolve the final addresses of stored properties and functions. Non-final classes, without whole module optimization will still need dynamic dispatch and there would be performance issues.